# How does this simple JS slideshow keep playing even though there doesn't seem to be a loop

Tags: javascript, html

It seems like the slideshow (code below) would only play once and do nothing afterwards. What part of it keeps it playing forever? Is it the "setTimeout()" part?

JS code:

```
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var eee;
    var slidesArray = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (eee = 0; eee < slidesArray.length; eee++) {
       slidesArray[eee].style.display =  "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > slidesArray.length) {
        myIndex = 1
    }    
    slidesArray[myIndex-1].style.display =  "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

HTML code (if needed):

```
<div class= "slideshow-display-container">
        <img class="mySlides" src="Pictures/Slideshows/HomepageSlideshow/Slideshow1.png" style= "width:100% ">
        <img class="mySlides" src="Pictures/Slideshows/HomepageSlideshow/Slideshow2.png" style= "width:100% ">
        <img class="mySlides" src="Pictures/Slideshows/HomepageSlideshow/Slideshow3.png" style= "width:100% ">
</div>
```

Comment: `Is it the "setTimeout()" part` - yes.  You call carousel once manually, and the last thing it does is schedule itself to run again in two seconds, which when it runs - schedules itself to run again, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The carousel function is using [recursion](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-recursive-function/) to call itself every two seconds in the following line:

```js
setTimeout(carousel, 2000);
```